# Dask Custom Graph Vizualisation

Tags: graphviz, dask

I'm trying to visualize a custom graph, but the boxes appear without any label. I'm using dask 2.3.0 and have correctly installed graphviz.
Here is the output I get on the example presented at https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html#example.

```
from dask import visualize

def load(filename):
    pass

def clean(data):
    pass

def analyze(sequence_of_data):
    pass

def store(result):
    pass

dsk = {'load-1': (load, 'myfile.a.data'),
       'load-2': (load, 'myfile.b.data'),
       'load-3': (load, 'myfile.c.data'),
       'clean-1': (clean, 'load-1'),
       'clean-2': (clean, 'load-2'),
       'clean-3': (clean, 'load-3'),
       'analyze': (analyze, ['clean-%d' % i for i in [1, 2, 3]]),
       'store': (store, 'analyze')}

visualize(dsk)
```

[image: Output graph]

Any help is welcome.
Dimitry